# Como "esconder" a chave de uma API antes de colocar o projeto no GitHub?

Tags: javascript, api

Estou criando um projeto de um site que usa a API do Unsplash (que retorna imagens). O problema é: se eu adicionar a chamada à API no repositório remoto, minha `client_id` será exposta, pois a URL de acesso é:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=[minha-id]
```

E se eu não enviar essa informação, o GitHub Pages não irá funcionar.

É possível esconder essa informação (ou armazená-la) em um local que não seja público e que a aplicação continue funcionando?

Comment: Você pode utilizar variáveis de ambiente para isso. Pacotes como o [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) podem ajudar, embora não sejam totalmente necessários.

Comment: Variáveis de ambiente no GitHub Pages?

Comment: @LauroMoraes, como assim GitHub pages? O AP não falou em nenhum momento sobre GitHub pages...

Comment: @LuizFelipe ele comentou na pergunta "para por no meu portfolio no github" e "portanto o Pages do github tb não..." logo imagino ser páginas estaticas não?

Comment: @LauroMoraes, realmente. Aí complica mesmo, não tinha prestado atenção nesse "detalhe". Uma outra opção seria usar algum serviço como Vercel ou Netlify para permitir uma etapa de "build" customizada para o site estático, aí a variável de ambiente se tornaria uma opção viável, ainda mantendo o site estático. Fora isso, no GitHub pages mesmo, realmente, não cabe usar variável de ambiente mesmo não. :/

Comment: eu recomendaria fazer um proxy com cloudworker da Cloudflare ou usar glitch.com ... mas necessitaria estudar a documentação. Assim daria para esconder a chave da API

Comment: Olá M.F, coloque essa key em um arquivo como um .env ou .ini e esse arquivo não deverá ser enviado ao git, então coloque o env ou ini no .gitignore para evitar subir e carregue esse valor chamado pela sua aplicação em uma variavel que vai substituir o `[minha-id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você for colocar no GitHub, então poderá utilizar o Github Pages com repositório privado, porém isso não resolve o seu problema, pois toda vez que essa API for chamada, qualquer um poderá ver os parâmetros (no caso, `client_id`), bastando apenas inspecionar as requests pelo próprio navegador.

Para garantir que ninguém verá essa chave, a chamada da API deverá ser realizada por um servidor backend, e não diretamente no frontend. No GitHub Pages não é possível hospedar um servidor backend.

Em resumo, deveria ser assim:

1. O frontend (no caso o GitHub Pages) chama uma API para um servidor backend;
2. O seu servidor backend chama a API para o Unsplash;
3. O Unsplash responde algum dado para o seu servidor;
4. Seu servidor responde para o frontend.

Você poderá utilizar serviços gratuitos (como o Heroku) para hospedar o seu backend. Recomendo utilizar o framework Express com Axios.

Basicamente, o seu servidor backend seria:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var axios = require('axios');


app.get('/sua-rota', function(req, res) {
  //chama a api do Unsplash
  axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=[minha-id]')
  .then(function (response) {
     res.send(responde.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
     res.status(500).send(error);
  })
});
```

Agora, no seu projeto do GitHub, ao invés de chamar a API do Unsplash, deverá chamar a API do seu servidor. Se você hospedar no Heroku, será algo assim: `nome-do-site.herokuapp.com/sua-rota`