# Usar dotevn no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tendo problemas com o uso de `dotenv`, ele não funciona quando tento pelo navegador, estou fazendo apenas um exemplo simples. Abaixo vou dar a situação dos arquivos:

- index.js

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import express from 'express'

dotenv.config()

const valor = process.env.SECRET;
console.log(valor);
```

- .env

```
SECRET=789
```

- index.html: Como usei a tag script

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Error retornado pelo navegador:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv/config". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

---

Já tentei colocar um `/` na importação, mas só retornou outro error

```
import '/dotenv/config'
import express from '/express'
```

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Estou usando a extensão live server para poder rodar a `modulação` pelo navegador

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Acabei encontrando uma solução, para situações mais delicadas, consiste em criar uma API para esconder os dados, para depois enviar a resposta em formato json, para algum básico como isso não vale a pena, mas para algum mais delicado como chave de API é mais indicado.

Encontrei essa resposta aqui no stackOverflow: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477756/como-esconder-a-chave-de-uma-api-antes-de-colocar-o-projeto-no-github#:~:text=Para%20garantir%20que%20ningu%C3%A9m%20ver%C3%A1,poss%C3%ADvel%20hospedar%20um%20servidor%20backend](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477756/como-esconder-a-chave-de-uma-api-antes-de-colocar-o-projeto-no-github#:%7E:text=Para%20garantir%20que%20ningu%C3%A9m%20ver%C3%A1,poss%C3%ADvel%20hospedar%20um%20servidor%20backend).

Tem também esse vídeo do facebook da rocketSeat falando sobre: https://www.facebook.com/rocketseat/videos/vai-consumir-outra-api-e-precisa-esconder-a-chave-de-acesso-o-codedrops45-tem-um/473894586882837/

Vídeo que ele fala (CodeDrops #45): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYlz3SmNXQQ

edit: acabei trazendo a pergunta de uma forma um tanto difícil de entender onde queria chegar, já que a ideia era trabalhar com dados sensíveis mas não falei na pergunta, então peço desculpas pela forma em que foi escrita